# Consume an rpc-style soap webservice using Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-boot

Im trying to consume an RPC-Style Soap WebService with Spring, I'm using this guide http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/ as an example.  I'm stuck at the "...WebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request..." because the XJC task doesnt generate the resquest Class, this is the wsdl of the service im trying to implement:

```
        <wsdl:definitions name="AuthenticationService" targetNamespace="http://authservices.ws.gt.company.com/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://authservices.ws.gt.company.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
           <wsdl:types>
              <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://authservices.ws.gt.company.com/" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                 <xs:complexType name="userInformationResponse">
                    <xs:sequence>
                       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="alias" type="xs:string"/>
                       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="bussinessPhone" type="xs:string"/>
                       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="department" type="xs:string"/>
                       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="email" type="xs:string"/>
                       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="errorMessage" type="xs:string"/>
                       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="firt" type="xs:string"/>
                       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="groups" type="tns:userInformationGroups"/>
                       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="last" type="xs:string"/>
                       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mobilePhone" type="xs:string"/>
                       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="title" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                 </xs:complexType>
                 <xs:complexType name="userInformationGroups">
                    <xs:sequence>
                       <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="group" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                 </xs:complexType>
              </xs:schema>
           </wsdl:types>
           <wsdl:message name="requestUserInfo">
              <wsdl:part name="ldapId" type="xsd:int"/>
              <wsdl:part name="user" type="xsd:string"/>
              <wsdl:part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
           </wsdl:message>
           <wsdl:message name="requestUserInfoResponse">
              <wsdl:part name="userInfo" type="tns:userInformationResponse"/>
           </wsdl:message>
           <wsdl:portType name="AuthService">
              <wsdl:operation name="requestUserInfo">
                 <wsdl:input message="tns:requestUserInfo" name="requestUserInfo"/>
                 <wsdl:output message="tns:requestUserInfoResponse" name="requestUserInfoResponse"/>
              </wsdl:operation>
           </wsdl:portType>
           <wsdl:binding name="AuthenticationServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:AuthService">
              <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
              <wsdl:operation name="requestUserInfo">
                 <soap:operation soapAction="" style="rpc"/>
                 <wsdl:input name="requestUserInfo">
                    <soap:body namespace="http://authservices.ws.gt.company.com/" use="literal"/>
                 </wsdl:input>
                 <wsdl:output name="requestUserInfoResponse">
                    <soap:body namespace="http://authservices.ws.gt.company.com/" use="literal"/>
                 </wsdl:output>
              </wsdl:operation>
           </wsdl:binding>
           <wsdl:service name="AuthenticationService">
              <wsdl:port binding="tns:AuthenticationServiceSoapBinding" name="AuthServicePort">
                 <soap:address location="http://HOST/authservices/AuthService"/>
              </wsdl:port>
           </wsdl:service>
        </wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Are you using Maven. Did you run the build task to generate the XJC classes?

Comment: AFAIK Spring WS only works for document driven webservices and not for RPC style web services.

Comment: Marten, I think this is client-side only. So the same code as the GS guide should work fine. I suspect the XJC task has simply not been executed.

Comment: @gansodesoya: any luck with the above problem?

Comment: @gansodesoya I had the same issue and my solution was to change the wsdl to use document style instead of rpc.